# What do you italicize when you create a compound word or worldplay?

Tags: formatting

For example, the mix of *sup* and *herb*: *supherb*.

I want to show that it's a made up word and a playword related to herbivores animals. What should I italicize? sup, herb, or the whole word?

Answer (score 1):

There are no rules for comedy.

If you really want to italicize, I suggest italicizing the word's least obvious component as to call attention to it.

In the specific case of supherb, italicize sup*herb*.